# Sidebar Navigation with toggle hide/show and font-awesome

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, dom, navigation

I'm trying to build a sidebar with a tree navigation. I'm using Bootstrap and jQuery-

I want to hide the nested submenu(s). Then when you click on 
`<a class="main-caret"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span></a>`, the submenu appears and the font-awesome class fa-caret-right gets removed and swapped for 
fa-caret-down. When you click on the link again, I want to menu to toggle back to hide and have the `<a>` class change back to caret-down.

I've been trying to write a jQuery function but I only seem to get the show/hide part to work.

Thoughts?

```
<ul class="list-unstyled sidebar-nav">
  <li><a href="#">Applying for Aid</a></li>
  <li><a class="main-caret"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span></a> <a href="#">Graduates</a>
    <ul class="sidebar-submenu">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span></a> <a href="#">Graduates</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Graduates</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Graduates</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>


  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> College of Professional Studies</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> School of Law</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Veterans</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this scripts

```js
$(function() {

  $('.sidebar-nav li a').click(function(e) {
  var ul = $(this).parent().find('ul');
    if (ul.length !== 0 ) {
       $(this).toggleClass('open').parent().find('ul').slideToggle(); 
  } else {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');    
  }
  e.preventDefault(); 
  
});

});
```

```css
ul.sidebar-nav {list-style:none;}
ul.sidebar-nav li ul { display:none; } 
ul.sidebar-nav li a {}
ul.sidebar-nav li a span.fa-caret-right { 
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
 transform: rotate(0deg);
}
ul.sidebar-nav li a.open span.fa-caret-right { 
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: rotate(-90deg);  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-unstyled sidebar-nav">
<li><a href="#">Applying for Aid</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="main-caret"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Graduates</a>
<ul class="sidebar-submenu">
<li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span>Graduates</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Graduates</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Graduates</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> College of Professional Studies</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> School of Law</a></li>
<li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-caret-right"></span> Veterans</a></li>
                    </ul>
```